# ASP.NET MVC - Help defining route entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

i want to build a route entry for a url **http://example.com/foo** which should map to **Index(string foo)** action method of a controller named **User**.

At the same time the default Home Controller should not be affected and should work normally

any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I configure the global.config to allow for root path to actionMethod in MVC2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353892/how-would-i-configure-the-global-config-to-allow-for-root-path-to-actionmethod-in)

Comment: See my answer to the dupe question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353892/how-would-i-configure-the-global-config-to-allow-for-root-path-to-actionmethod-in/3353954#3353954

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting this before the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "FooRoute",
    "{foo}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        foo = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```